# Implement typescript generic in Vue mixin using class component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-class-components

I just migrated my Vue project to Typescript, but there one missing situation I need to manage.

I need to handle some paginated tables in my app, so I created a `Table` mixin that handles pagination on my collection of records:

```
@Component
export default class Table<T> extends Vue {
  records: T[] = []

  page: number = 0
  length: number = 20

  get total () {
    return this.records.length
  }

  get visibleRecords(): T[] {
    return this.records.slice(this.page*this.length, (this.page+1)*this.length)
  }

  public changePage (newPage: number) {
    this.page = newPage
  }
}
```

Each component that renders the table, extends the mixin, populate the `records` property and simply displays the result of `visibleRecords` computed property. A basic component:

```
export default class Sampletable extends Mixins(Table) {

  records: RecordType[] = [ .... my data array ... ]
}

<template>
  <table>
    <tr v-for="record in visibleRecords">
      ....
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>
```

This works, but by calling 'visibleRecords' I lose the knowledge of my data type (`RecordType` in the example). What I need is to have typescript understand that `visibleRecords` (implemented in the mixin) returns the same data type of the `records` property (that is overridden in the component implementing thr mixin)

I tried to implement the `Table` mixin with a generic (as you can see in the previous code) but it doesn't work, because I can't define the generic type when extending the Mixin:

```
export default class Sampletable extends Mixins(Table<RecordType>)
```

throws an error.

Is there a way to accomplish this? any suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

Try do it like this:

```js
export default class Sampletable extends Mixins<Table<RecordType>>(Table) {
...
```

source: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/289#issuecomment-471388618

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, I get 'TS2315: Type 'Vue' is not generic.' error

Comment: `extends mixins<T>(YourMixin)` normally should work. In the actual mixin class definition the mixin should extend Vue; `export default class MixInName<T extends TypeX> extends Vue`